# cvs --version works, cvs import gets can't find cvs

Tags: git, bash, cvs

I have a cvs repository and am trying to work with it as I move things into git.
I am running OS X 10.12.4 and my group membership is admin.  My home-brew installation of cvs is in /usr/local/Cellar and linked to it in /usr/local/bin/cvs and all belong to the group admin.

I can cd into a directory and type cvs --version and get the current cvs version.
Then when I type cvs import new_project START initial, I get 
'bash can't find cvs'
Also cvs log gives bash can't find cvs'
What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  During a recent update of the operating system on my local server where the repository is, OS X Sierra removed or deleted cvs and home-brew!
The issue was not cvs on my laptop, but when cvs tried to execute on the server, it was not found.  I ran the command under the home-brew site to install home-brew on the server, then did brew install cvs.

After that cvs works fine on my laptop, checking out and in from the server.

The message was confusing as it did not say cvs not found on xxx.yyy, and implied it was a path problem on my laptop.